# How to Load Fastai model and predict it on single image

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, resnet, fast-ai

I have trained a fastai model using Kaggle notebook, it has saved the model but how to load the model is the problem, i have tried different methods like the method given below. Even it does load the model it doesn't have any predict function only thing I can see is model.eval().
The second problem is when the model was trained on google collab it didn't even get the single image, I did try to convert the image to NumPy way and another way but both didn't work out.

I am attaching the kaggle link of model training, the saved model and the test images in last after this code

```
#Code for Loading model
from fastai import * 
from fastai.vision import *
import torch
loc = torch.load('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data Exports/35k data/stage-1.pth')
body = create_body(models.resnet18, True, None)
data_classes = 4
nf = callbacks.hooks.num_features_model(body) * 2
head = create_head(nf, data_classes, None, ps=0.5, bn_final=False)
model = nn.Sequential(body, head)
```

[Kaggle Model](https://www.kaggle.com/tanushsavadi/retina-damage-classification-95-accuracy)

[Test Images From Kaggle Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/kermany2018)

[Saved Model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qjfx_oEEALLfY2S4egwmVSAfLq_6t5ap?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

[How to load pytorch models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-for-inference):

```py
loc = torch.load('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data Exports/35k data/stage-1.pth')
model = ... # build your model
model.load_state_dict(loc)
model.eval()
```

Now you should be able to simply use the forward pass to generate your predictions:

```
input = ... # your input image
pred = model(input) # your class predictions
```

Don't forget to convert your inputs to torch tensors first, you might want to use a [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#preparing-your-data-for-training-with-dataloaders) for ease of use.

Comment: I am sure gonna try it. hope it works out